# Issues running beginner programs in CMD using JDK 14

Tags: java

I am currently using the "Java A Beginner's Guide Eighth Edition" by Herbert Schildt to learn to program using Java. I have no prior programming experience and am running into an error.

I have JDK 14 installed to my C drive. After a long time of having compiler issues where I could not find the file, I believe I have solved that issue. But now am encountering the following;

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

C:\Users\*****>javac -version
javac 14.0.1

C:\Users\*****\mywork> java example
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: example has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

C:\Users\*****\mywork>
```

Comment: The JRE was removed as of Java 11. Your book is slightly out of date. Uninstall the Java 8 JRE you have installed. Or downgrade to a Java 8 JDK and just focus on learning Java 8 for now.

Comment: You have different version of jre and jdk installed on your system. @310ToPoona. Uninstall your jre. Check your path which points to jre. you compiled your program with different version of java compiler and trying to run it with different version of jre. Remove that jre path from your path

Comment: You could also try this: https://sdkman.io/ it is quite easy to set up and allows switching between java versions quickly (and you will have to in the future anyway).

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; and class names in PascalCase.

Comment: @MCEmperor, that has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri No, it hasn't. But it's still important.

Comment: @MCEmperor agree, extremely important.

Comment: Share your source code with us in your post .@310ToPoona

Answer (score 2):

Check your environment variable `PATH` whether it has a reference to `Java` bin directory or not. It may be weirdly configured, referring to the `Jdk8` and to `jdk14` as well.. but I'm not sure what's happening there. For some strange reason, your `javac` runs `Jdk14` binary, and `java` - runs from `Jdk8` binaries.

Then I'd have checked `where java` in the `cmd`, and this way, I'd see where my `java.exe` file[s] are located.

Then, you'd probably want to correct your Java installation, and see if you have several binaries installed on your machine (jdk14 and jdk8), maybe you want to delete one of those, or - if you want to keep both - make sure environment variable is set correctly.

Finally, you might also find useful to check `echo %JAVA_HOME%` (for Widows) or echo $JAVA_HOME (for Linux), in order to see, where your `JAVA_HOME` refers to.

**Note**, that your problem can also be attributed to your IDE. For example, if you have an `IntelliJ` which uses its built-in Jdk, it might need to be reconfigured.

The problem prevails because you're using later version (14) of Java to compile the files, and you're running them with the lower version (8) of Java.

Comment: I have now uninstalled Java version 8 and am seeing the following; ```C:\Users\*****\mywork>java example
Error: Could not find or load main class example
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example (wrong name: example)```

Comment: Good, you solved one problem. Now that's another problem. What is the package of your Java class which holds `public static void main` method?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, uninstall Java-8 from your system. Then, compile and run your program as follows:

```
javac example.java
java example
```

However, starting with Java-11, if `example.java` file has the top-level `class example` with `main`, you do not even need to compile it using `javac` i.e. you can run it directly as follows:

```
java example.java
```

On a side note, you should follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the class, `example` should be named as `Example`.

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: This helped out, after uninstalling JDK version 8, I managed to solve the issue by changing the first line of my program was previously ```class Example {```  which was causing  issues based on case sensitivity